# How do I avoid improperly boosting view count on my question during the ingathering contest?

Tags: discussion, views, ingathering-contest

The page for the ingathering contest links to a brief meta.SE discussion that says views are counted conservatively but viewing your own entry does count.  I posted a recent question and chose it for the contest; in the course of participating in that question I'm naturally going to view the page, but I'm not trying to artificially drive up views.  If I knew that, say, all views from a user wtihin N hours count as one view, I could make sure to clump comment reviews and the like to minimize my own footprint.  Can anybody clarify how this works?

(I know I can read responses through my profile page, but obviously I can't post comments that way and it can get confusing when there are comments on multiple answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks very much for your concern for being ethical about this.

I'd say not to worry about it. If you spend more time on the site as a result of the contest, then that counts as a positive result of the contest! If you spend time on your own question because it's your content, then that's "natural" participation anyway and should count no less than anyone else's.

In addition, I'm really hoping that the winning contestant will bring in on the order of hundreds of views from the outside, so the few extra views you may generate should hopefully not be the deciding factor.

Of course, it would probably be unethical to do something like set up a bot to constantly reload the question page, or something like that, but I trust that no one's going to do anything like that.

Comment: I would say that the "probably" in your last paragraph is not needed: bots would be beyond the pale, I think we'd all agree. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will count as multiple views if you are logged in from the same computer in the same day. I don't know how it works without all those conditions, but you should be able to view it just like anyone else, no?